# Getting RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, pygame

[image]creating a minesweeper game in pygame and i am getting a recursion error when running my code. how do i mitigate this? This is the code I have that checks to see if the clicked grid square is empty and if it is then it reveals that grid square as well as all the adjacent squares. the section that is getting this error is below:

```
def reveal_empty(rn,c, grid, revealed,box):
    if grid[rn][c] != '0' and grid[rn][c] != '*':
        revealed[rn][c] = True
    if grid[rn][c] == '0':
        revealed[rn][c] = True
        # change row above
        if rn-1 > -1:
            r = grid[rn-1]

            if c-1 > -1:
                if not r[c-1] == '*':
                    revealed[rn-1][c-1] = True
                    reveal_empty(rn-1,c-1, grid, revealed,box)

            if not r[c] == '*':
                revealed[rn-1][c] = True
                reveal_empty(rn-1,c, grid, revealed,box)

            if c+1 < 10:
                if not r[c+1] == '*':
                    revealed[rn-1][c+1] = True
                    reveal_empty(rn-1,c+1, grid, revealed,box)

        #change same row                
        r = grid[rn]

        if c-1 > -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*':
                revealed[rn][c-1] + True
                reveal_empty(rn,c-1, grid, revealed,box)
        if c+1 < 10:
            if not r[c+1] == '*':
                revealed[rn][c+1] = True
                reveal_empty(rn,c+1, grid, revealed,box)

        #change row below
        if rn+1 < 11:
            r = grid[rn + 1]

            if c-1 > -1:
                if not r[c-1] == '*':
                    revealed[rn+1][c-1] = True
                    reveal_empty(rn+1,c-1, grid, revealed,box)

            if not r[c] == '*':
                revealed[rn+1][c] = True
                reveal_empty(rn+1,c, grid, revealed,box)

            if c+1 < 11:
                if not r[c+1] == '*':
                    revealed[rn+1][c+1] = True
                    reveal_empty(rn+1,c+1, grid, revealed,box)
```

Comment: Are you getting: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  This posting has no input, no tracing output, and no driver to show the error.  Are you expecting us to eye-check your code without references?

Comment: @Prune sorry I didn't want to overload with my entire code I will post it below.

Comment: @Prune I cannot add my whole code as it is too long

Comment: Read my comment again: we specifically ask you *not* to post your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* you have this problem because there is no quick exit-clause for your recursive function.  I suspect that because you don't check to see if the cell is already revealed ( `revealed[row][col] == True` ), then it never exits - it keeps recursing for ones already half-done in the processing queue (stack).

Maybe a quick check at the beginning of the function will fix it:

```
def reveal_empty( row, col, grid, revealed, box ):
    if ( revealed[row][col] == False ):
        # do recursive check else here!
    else:
        print("Cell[%d][%d] is already revealed" % ( row, col ) )
```

Comment: I am getting RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
Also adding a check at the beginning of the function takes care of the recursion error but doesn't reveal the cells like I want.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to add a check to each step of the recursion to check if the value has been revealed yet. see below:

```
# change row above
    if rn-1 > -1:
        r = grid[rn-1]

        if c-1 >= -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*' and revealed[rn-1][c-1] == False:
                revealed[rn-1][c-1] = True
                if grid[rn-1][c-1] == '0':
                    reveal_empty(rn-1,c-1, grid, revealed,box)

        if not r[c] == '*' and revealed[rn-1][c] == False:
            revealed[rn-1][c] = True
            if grid[rn-1][c] == '0':
                reveal_empty(rn-1,c, grid, revealed,box)

        if c+1 < 10:
            if not r[c+1] == '*' and revealed[rn-1][c+1] == False:
                revealed[rn-1][c+1] = True
                if grid[rn-1][c+1] == '0':
                    reveal_empty(rn-1,c+1, grid, revealed,box)

    #change same row                
    r = grid[rn]

    if c-1 > -1:
        if not r[c-1] == '*' and revealed[rn][c-1] == False:
            revealed[rn][c-1] + True
            if grid[rn][c-1] == '0':
                reveal_empty(rn,c-1, grid, revealed,box)
    if c+1 < 10:
        if not r[c+1] == '*' and revealed[rn][c+1] == False:
            revealed[rn][c+1] = True
            if grid[rn][c+1] == '0':
                reveal_empty(rn,c+1, grid, revealed,box)

    #change row below
    if rn+1 < 11:
        r = grid[rn + 1]

        if c-1 > -1:
            if not r[c-1] == '*' and revealed[rn+1][c-1] == False:
                revealed[rn+1][c-1] = True
                if grid[rn+1][c-1] == '0':
                    reveal_empty(rn+1,c-1, grid, revealed,box)

        if not r[c] == '*' and revealed[rn+1][c] == False:
            revealed[rn+1][c] = True
            if grid[rn+1][c] == '0':
                reveal_empty(rn+1,c, grid, revealed,box)

        if c+1 < 11:
            if not r[c+1] == '*' and revealed[rn+1][c+1] == False:
                revealed[rn+1][c+1] = True
                if grid[rn+1][c+1] == '0':
                    reveal_empty(rn+1,c+1, grid, revealed,box)
```